# How to tell if a ThreadPool thread died silently

Tags: c#, threadpool

I'm in DLL hell right now trying to make my code work within the framework of a different application. For the longest time I was thrashing around trying to understand why my methods weren't being called when they were clearly being enqueued to the ThreadPool.

It finally turned out to be that one particular DLL had to be in the same folder as the calling method, or failing to find it, the ThreadPool thread would either die or ditch the job silently (like a ninja).

Obviously, the solution compiled perfectly and threw no errors, as the DLL in question was being built, just to a different folder. This isn't the first time that a ThreadPool thread has just died silently on me because of a misplaced DLL.

1. What exactly is happening to my threads when they disappear?
2. How do I figure out that this is happening in the future? Would there be a log file somewhere by any chance?

**Some code:**

```
protected void Enqueue()
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => Process());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging code here (no issues)
    }
}

protected void Process()
{
    // A breakpoint here will never be called

    try {       
        // Code that calls into offensive DLL
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Logging code
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put try/catch around worker thread entry function, and logging errors to see an unhandled exception that may be killing your thread?

Comment: subscribe to Application.ThreadException .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836766/c-sharp-catching-exception-which-is-occuring-on-threadpool  ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714520/why-exceptions-raised-on-threadpool-thread-are-not-handled-by-main-thread-in-c-s

Comment: @LB2 Shouldn't that tear down the process?

Comment: Threads should rarely just "disappear".  They *could*, but that usually means the whole app disappears.  +1 to subscribing to the ThreadException events.  Also, wrap the body of your thread entry in a try/catch and output any exceptions that occur.  Once you do that you can post back any exceptions you get and someone can give you more specific advice.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Thanks! I'll try the subscription to ThreadException.

Comment: @LB2: It's not exception logging that's the problem - I posted some sample code. The method is queued to the ThreadPool with no issues, but will never be called. It just dies somewhere in between.

Comment: Application.ThreadException is bad advice, it only triggers for exceptions raised on the UI thread and makes plenty of noise by itself.  Broken logging is the obvious failure mode here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Good point. Is it possible that threadpool that manages these threads swallows the exception?  Don't know...

Comment: You may also be interested in using the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event to be notified of any unobserved exceptions in background tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Process contains the call to the DLL. If so, the exception is thrown on JIT of process, and so you cannot catch it within Process. Use one more layer of indirection before calling the DLL to be sure of being able to log it.

```
protected void Enqueue()
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => Process());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging code here (no issues)
    }
}

protected void Process()
{
    try {
        Process2();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Logging code
    }
}

protected void Process2()
{
            // Code that calls into offensive DLL
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What baffles me is that static methods contained within this DLL not only compiled, but even worked, whereas instance methods threw MissingMethodExceptions. I didn't think the JIT compiler made a distinction between the two.

Comment: If you're getting MissingMethod rather than not found, than there's another version of the DLL somewhere you're picking up (say, PATH).